# Where to format data from a JSON Object

Tags: android, json

I have to convert data from metric to imperial, depending on the user's preferences.
But I wonder where to convert this data. Should I do it in my AsyncTask that retrieves the JSON Object and parse value to the model or should I simply do it in the UI thread in my fragment when getting the values from the model?

I'm asking this because I will have to adapt my Strings when calling setText() depending on User's preferences(eg: °C or °F, m or Ft).
Just want to know what is best in this case

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

For parsing JSON data you should do the parsing steps in doInBackground of AsyncTask. And after parsing set the parsed data to the fields in onPostExecute. Check this [Android JSON parsing tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) if you are new to JSON parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Do not perform formatting operations on UI thread, as it causes performance issues for you app if data is huge, you can even do text formatting in `onPostExecute()` method.